# How to access a text Variable in SwiftUI in my Storyboard

Tags: swift, swiftui, storyboard

```
struct ContentView: View
{
@State var text = ""
@State var isEditing = false
var body: some View
{
    
        iTextField("text", text: $text, isEditing: $isEditing)
            .style(height: 58, backgroundColor: nil, accentColor: Color(red: 0.30, green: 
      0.76, blue: 0.85), font: nil, paddingLeading: 25, cornerRadius: 6, hasShadow: true, 
       image: Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass"))
        
    }
}
```

I have this code above in my View that is written in SwiftUI. How can I access the text value inside that textField in my storyboard code?

```
class ViewController: UIHostingController<ContentView>
 {
       required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: coder,rootView: ContentView());
         }

     override func viewDidLoad()
     {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
     }


  }
```

Comment: What does "access" mean here? Do you want your storyboard to get notified when it changes? Do you want to be able to change it and have the changes update the view?

Comment: I would like to be able to get the data from the textfield when the user presses return on the keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I had to do to fix this.

```
  struct MyTextField: View
     {
        @ObservedObject var model: TextFieldModel

        var body: some View
        {
            iTextField("Email:", text: $model.text, isEditing: 
             $model.isEditing)
            .onReturn{
                print($model.text)
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: 
             Notification.Name(rawValue: 
             "checkTicker"), object: nil)
            }
           
       }
      }


        class TextFieldModel: ObservableObject
         {
         init() { }
            @Published var text = ""
           @Published var isEditing = false
         }

      class ViewController: UIHostingController<MyTextField>
      {
         private var model = TextFieldModel()
    
         required init?(coder: NSCoder)
        {
           super.init(coder: coder,rootView: MyTextField(model: model));
        }
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
        #selector(checkTicker), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: 
         "checkTicker"), object: nil)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @objc func checkTicker()
    {
        print("hello2 ", model.text)
        
    }

  }
```

Comment: This is generally the right approach. You could either pass a model (like you did), or a `Binding`, or even a callback closure - all depends on what makes sense. You don't need `NotificationCenter` - just use `model.$text.sink { print($0) }.store(in: &cancellable)`